# Accessing number of tokens and staked tokens not working on single node testnet

Tags: cleos, nodeos

I have set up a single node testnet as shown below:

```
nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --contracts-console --verbose-http-errors --delete-all-blocks
```

Then I have set up an account called "hamnett". And issued myself 100 EOS:

```
cleos create account eosio hamnett key key

cleos push action eosio.token issue '[ "hamnett", "100.0000 EOS", "memo" ]' -p eosio@active
```

Finally, I want to check how much balance I have, and how much I have staked. So I type:

```
cleos get account hamnett
```

and the result is:

```
permissions: 
     owner     1:    1 key
        active     1:    1 key
memory: 
     quota:       unlimited  used:      3.02 KiB  

net bandwidth: 
     used:               unlimited
     available:          unlimited
     limit:              unlimited

cpu bandwidth:
     used:               unlimited
     available:          unlimited
     limit:              unlimited
```

**Why is everything showing up as unlimited and why is my balance not shown?**

Note: `key` is not the public key, just trying to keep everything readable.

Comment: try `$ cleos set contract eosio path/to/build/contracts/eosio.system -p eosio`

Comment: I did this, but it didn't change anything

Comment: afterwards, just create accounts with `$ cleos system newaccount` providing the relevant values for `--stake-net` and `--stake-cpu`

Comment: So now I have: `cleos system newaccount eosio.system hamnett --stake-net "1 EOS" --stake-cpu "1 EOS" --buy-ram-kbytes 8 key key`. The error this gives is `Unknown action buyrambytes in contract eosio
code: eosio, action: buyrambytes, args: {"payer":"eosio.system","receiver":"hamnett","bytes":8192}`

Comment: can't test right now, but some things i would change are (1) you don't need an `eosio.system` account because you upload `eosio.system` with `eosio` so in your command after `newcommand` i would use `eosio` as the creator (i don't know if you created an `eosio.system` account); (2) I would explicitly write the values with 4 decimal places (`1.0000 EOS` instead of `1 EOS`); (3) i would try `SYS` instead of `EOS` if your code was compiled using the default settings. I'll try to post later a clearer explanation and step by step process that works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is everything showing up as unlimited and why is my balance not shown?

Accounts created before deploying `eosio.system` don't have bandwidth/CPU limits because there isn't a contract deployed to handle this. In regards to balance, it is not clear if you created tokens before issuing them (creating is a necessary first step)

There are quite a few steps to accomplish what you're trying to do, and, from the comments, it seems like there may be several issues that are difficult to reproduce.

I suggest following the [BIOS Boot Sequence](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence) tutorial in the official docs as it walks you through this exact process.

Note you can get currency balance with:

`cleos get currency balance eosio.token hamnett`